# Spring Sort.Direction to get a randomize/shuffled result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I have following code to get ascending order of the total result and later I paginate it to chunk of 5 rows.

```
new PageRequest(currentIndex, recordsToFetch, Direction.ASC, "createdDate")
```

However, Now I want to get random results, 
First I thought of using RAND() but after reading some posts find out that it’s a huge performance bug and avoid using it. Then I tried to remove the order by attribute from `Pagerquest()` like below and it didn't work.

```
new PageRequest(currentIndex, recordsToFetch, null, "createdDate")
```

I tried to find a post or a code to do this using Direction(`org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction`) and had no luck finding one. 
Is there anyway, that I can shuffle the total results without affecting the pagination.